# Maven custom plugin. Array oj custom pbjects

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I want make pairs of files, looks like

```
<configuration>
              <params>
                <param>
                  <wsdl>${basedir}/File1.wsdl</wsdl>
                  <result>D:/file1</result>
                 </param>
                 <param>
                  <wsdl>${basedir}/File2.wsdl</wsdl>
                  <result>D:/file2</result>
                </param>
               </params>
            </configuration>
```

here is code

```
    /**
 *
 * @goal merge 
 * @requiresProject true
 */
public class MavenPlugin extends AbstractMojo
{


    /**
        * 
        * @parameter
        * @requared
        */
       public List<TwoFiles> params;

       public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
       {
          if (params == null || params.isEmpty())
          {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("params is requared");
          } 



....  

public class TwoFiles
{

   public File wsdl;

   public File result;
}
```

Not working well.

any ideas?

**ANSWER:**

```
public class MainExecutor extends AbstractMojo
{
   /**
    * @parameter
    */
   private List<Param> params;
```

...

```
public class Param
{
   public File wsdl;

   public File result;
}
```

works well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you actually create an object for `<params/>` as well. Have it contain a `Set<TwoFiles> params`. I have faced this before and this is how I resolved it.

It's kind of stupid, I agree. However, the default support for collections is intended for simpler types, such as String-s. Apart from that, it's not really generics-oriented and Maven doesn't handle the guessing all that well.

Comment: No, create a separate class called `Params`. Add the `List<TwoFiles> params` to it. This should work.

Comment: Renaming class TwoFiles -> Param was helpful. No need put List<TwoFiles> to this class. Only renaming

Comment: Yeah, actually you're right, I got confused, but in the end -- that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do it this way:

```
<configuration>  
   <params>
     <param>
      <wsdl>${basedir}/File1.wsdl</wsdl>
      <result>D:/file1</result>
     </param>
     <param>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/File2.wsdl</wsdl>
        <result>D:/file2</result>
     </param>
   </params>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How did you test that? Integration test? mvn -X ?

Comment: in execute() method :: if (params == null) throw new ...    And I get this exception

Comment: I use this plugin in real project. If MavenPlugin class has two fields 'File' all works well. But now I want array of file-pair

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a List instead of an Array.

Comment: Renaming class TwoFiles -> Param was helpful